# Cannot get property after using jsonSplurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I'm a new on Jmeter, I'm using JSR223 PostProcessor to get some properties in the response. Unfortunately, my response is returned as a string json as below:

> "{\n  "trueOdds": "1.9047619047619047",\n  "displayOdds": "1.90",\n  "minStake": 50.0,\n  "maxStake": 105263,\n  "selectionId": "11318855000001015h",\n  "oddsStyle": "de",\n  "offerId": "1911208285033005"\n}"

Now I want to get trueOdds, displayOdds for using in the next request. I tried to use following code to get them:

> import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
>
> def jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
>
> def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
>
> def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonString);
>
> vars.put("trueOdds", object.trueOdds);
>
> vars.put("displayOdds", object.displayOdds);

But I get following error:

> ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223
> PostProcessor javax.script.ScriptException:
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: trueOdds for
> class: java.lang.String

Can anyone support to resolve this? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue given the following JSON payload:

```
{
  "trueOdds": "1.9047619047619047",
  "displayOdds": "1.90",
  "minStake": 50.0,
  "maxStake": 105263,
  "selectionId": "11318855000001015h",
  "oddsStyle": "de",
  "offerId": "1911208285033005"
}
```

Demo:

[image]

If your response looks **exactly** how you show it to us it's not a [valid JSON](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) therefore you need:

1. Remove first and last `"` via i.e. [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) function
2. Remove all occurrences of `\n` via i.e. [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) function

Suggested code amendment:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

def withoutQuotationMarks = jsonString.substring(1, jsonString.length() - 1)
def withoutLineBreaks = withoutQuotationMarks.replaceAll('\\\\n','')

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();

def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(withoutLineBreaks);

vars.put("trueOdds", object.trueOdds);

vars.put("displayOdds", object.displayOdds);
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hello, yes, the response is exactly how I showed you, so it is a string in stead of JSON, the idea of substring/replace is great. I removed everything but keep only parameter name & value. Then extract them. Thanks!